# Activity call date based on "USER" APEX code help

Tags: apex, list-view

Purpose:  I have a field called My_Last_Call__c in Contact.  The purpose of this field is for the USER to see when they last called the client.  Since one client can be called by anyone, I want this field to populate the last call activity date based on USER.  Also, I would like to use this on the VIEW LIST in contact object.

Problem:  After updating the activity log, it populates the LAST date of the LAST user (not the current user).
Ex.
John Doe was called by Joe Smith 2/15/16.  So Joe Smith My_Last_Call__c = 2/15/16
John Doe was called by Jane Doe 2/19/16. So Jane Doe My_Last_Call__c = 2/19/16 
When we view the Contact View List it shows

John Doe My_Last_Call__c is 2/19/16 even if the use Joe Smith is logged in.

Where am I doing this wrong?

This is my APEX.

```
trigger MyLastCallDate on Task (after insert, after update, after delete) 
{
    public String currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    public String oldUser=[select old_ID__c from User where id=:currentUser limit 1]
        [0].old_ID__c;
    Set<Id> con_set = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> con_list = new List<Contact>();
    for( Task T: Trigger.new )
    {
        {
            con_set.add(T.whoid);
        }
    }
    for(AggregateResult aggregateResult:[SELECT max(createdDate)MaxCDate,whoid FROM Task WHERE whoid IN: con_set AND Status ='Completed' AND (subject LIKE 'call%' OR subject LIKE 'outbound%') AND (CreatedbyId=:currentUser OR OLDOWNERID__C=:oldUser) group By whoid])
    {
        con_list.add(new Contact(Id=(id)aggregateResult.get('whoid'),My_Last_Call__c=date.valueof(aggregateResult.get('MaxCDate'))));
    }
    try
    {
        if(con_list !=null && con_list.size()>0)
        {
            update con_list;
        }
    }Catch(Exception ee){
        system.debug('Exception ***'+ee.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the data type of My_Last_Call__c? Date? String?

Comment: Is this query returning what you want...?? for(AggregateResult aggregateResult:[SELECT max(createdDate)MaxCDate,whoid FROM Task WHERE whoid IN: con_set AND Status ='Completed' AND (subject LIKE 'call%' OR subject LIKE 'outbound%') AND (CreatedbyId=:currentUser OR OLDOWNERID__C=:oldUser) group By whoid])

Comment: @sfdcfox To answer your questions... DATE

Comment: @amidstCloud It's returning date which is good but the date of the current activity not the date of the user activity.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to display the value by the currently logged in user, a single field is not going to work here. The problem is that you can only store one value at a time, and it will be based on the currently logged in user that closes the task. Instead, you need something dynamic. As a basic starter, you might do something like this:

## Class

```
public class LastActivityDateExtension {
    public Date lastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public LastActivityDateExtension(ApexPages.StandardController c) {
        try {
            lastActivityDate = [SELECT      ActivityDate
                                FROM        Task 
                                WHERE       IsClosed = TRUE
                                        AND WhoId = :c.getId()
                                        AND OwnerId IN (:UserInfo.getUserId())
                                ORDER BY    ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST
                                LIMIT       1].ActivityDate;
        } catch(QueryException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="LastActivityDateExtension">
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!lastActivityDate=null}" value="You have no activity history with this {!$ObjectType.Contact.Label}." />
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!lastActivityDate<>null}" value="Your last completed activity with this {!$ObjectType.Contact.Label} was on {!lastActivityDate}." />
</apex:page>
```

Simply add this page to your contact's page layout, and you'll get a short sentence that tells the user about their last activity date, if any, based on the logged in user.

For a List View, you'll need to use a similar technique-- create a page that utilizes the `recordSetVar` attribute to turn it into a list page, then add a custom button to your list views that use that page. There'd some pretty good examples out there on the web about how you'd do this.

Comment: In this sort of application, will you get performance improvement by stripping out `standardStylesheets`, etc?

Comment: There's no harm if you want to, but it's not necessary. I'd only worry if the standard sheets caused unwanted behavior. There's no discernable difference in loading time for a page of this size.

Comment: I bet I could post another question that would get under your skin (and net you a bunch of up-votes) with this one. :P

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks and I will try this tonight.  I will also keep you updated and see how it goes.  thanks again.